# Selenium Grid 2 - Parallelized datadriven tests

Tags: c#, selenium-grid, mbunit

I am pretty new in this area, so apologies for the question.
I am trying to run datadriven tests in parallel, using Selenium Grid2.

Here is my setup of the test:

```
    [Test]
    [Parallelizable]
    [Row("nl-NL")]
    [Row("fr-BE")]
      public void UsignUp(string locale)
    {
      //test to exexute

    }
```

When I run the test, 2 browser instances are starting, but they are entering the data in each other. So my tests are failing.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make sure that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with Selenium using C# but the first think you need is a "test runner" that has forking or parallelized capability to run unit tests in their own thread.   I looked on Google and couldn't figure it out.  In Java, there are lots of options, like Maven Surefire, Gradle, TestNG, etc.